# winRM Transport error since Ansible Upgrade

Tags: ansible

Im running an ansible playbook from a debian machine that connects with 3 hosts to deploy some features.

Since upgrading the ansible to 2.9.2 from 2.8 , I've repeatedly started to get errors from python libraries such as:

```py
     res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
     resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 323, in send_message
     response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 328, in _send_message_request
     response = self.session.send(prepared_request, timeout=self.read_timeout_sec)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
     timeout=timeout
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
     chunked=chunked,
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
     exc_info=True,
 Message: 'Failed to parse headers (url=%s): %s'
 Arguments: ('http://{{MY.DEST.IP}}:5985/wsman', HeaderParsingError("[StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''"))
```

MY.DEST.IP = my public IP

Port 5985 is open in the destination and i could connect with telnet.

Is there any issue known about the newest Ansible version?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: is it for any particular module or even win_ping fails

Comment: There is [an open issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/63180) that seems to fit your error message; are you using a `delegate_to:` in your playbook?